# Insert document with ReactiveMongo does not use BSONWriter or Reader

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I have the following class:

```
case class DeviceRegistration(deviceData: DeviceData,
                              pin: String,
                              created: DateTime) {}
```

Type `DeviceData` is defined simply as 4 string fields.

I've been trying unsuccessfully to insert a type of `DeviceRegistration` to a mongo collection. I want to make sure the date is stored as a ISODate and not a NumberLong, so I implemented custom readers and writers.

```
  implicit object DeviceDataWriter extends BSONDocumentWriter[DeviceData] {
    def write(data: DeviceData): BSONDocument = BSONDocument(
      DEVICE_ID_KEY -> data.deviceId,
      MODEL_KEY -> data.model,
      BRAND_KEY -> data.brand,
      MANUFACTURER_KEY -> data.manufacturer)
  }

  implicit object DeviceRegistrationWriter extends BSONDocumentWriter[DeviceRegistration] {
    def write(registration: DeviceRegistration): BSONDocument = BSONDocument(
      DEVICE_DATA_KEY -> registration.deviceData,
      PIN_KEY -> registration.pin,
      CREATED_KEY -> BSONDateTime(registration.created.getMillis))
  }

  implicit object DeviceDataReader extends BSONDocumentReader[DeviceData] {
    def read(doc: BSONDocument): DeviceData = {
      val deviceId = doc.getAs[String](DEVICE_ID_KEY).get
      val model = doc.getAs[String](MODEL_KEY)
      val brand = doc.getAs[String](BRAND_KEY)
      val manufacturer = doc.getAs[String](MANUFACTURER_KEY)
      DeviceData(deviceId, model, brand, manufacturer)
    }
  }

  implicit object DeviceRegistrationReader extends BSONDocumentReader[DeviceRegistration] {
    def read(doc: BSONDocument): DeviceRegistration = {
      val deviceData = doc.getAs[DeviceData](DEVICE_DATA_KEY).get
      val pin = doc.getAs[String](PIN_KEY).get
      val created = doc.getAs[BSONDateTime](CREATED_KEY).map(dt => new DateTime(dt.value))
      DeviceRegistration(deviceData, pin, created.get)
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to insert the document with the following code:

```
  def save(deviceRegistration: DeviceRegistration): Future[DeviceRegistration] = {
    deviceRegistrations.insert(deviceRegistration).map(result => deviceRegistration)
  }
```

To retrieve, I'm doing this:

```
  def findDeviceRegistrationRequest(deviceConfirmationData: DeviceConfirmationData) = {
    deviceRegistrations.find(BSONDocument("pin" -> deviceConfirmationData.pin))
      .one[DeviceRegistration](ReadPreference.Primary)
  }
```

The record is stored as this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56dea8d0d8cadd6ff70690d8"), "deviceData" : { "deviceId" : "kdsajkldjsalkda" }, "pin" : "9914", "created" : NumberLong("1457432783921") }
```

The created date is clearly not being serialized by my writer. It seems reactivemongo is using some default writer.

Likewise, when I read, I get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: (/created,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.date),WrappedArray())))
```

So it's clearly also not using my reader.

I didn't have any luck googling around. What am I missing?

I also tried to find a way to specifically set the writer and reader I want to use (instead of relying on the implicit mechanism), but I was not able to figure it out.

Any pointers in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of `DeviceData`.As long as `Date` is used as type property, it's properly serialized.

Comment: I guess you mean DeviceRegistration (which is the one that has a DateTime). Added that to the original question. I believe that a Date is serialized as a Long with the milliseconds (that's also the behaviour I get now). I need it to be a proper date in mongo so that I can use a TTL index.

Comment: Try `println(BSONDocument.pretty(implicitly[BSONWriter[DeviceRegistration, BSONDocument]].write(aRegistration)))`